# itemize inside an equation

Tags: equations, lists, itemize

I am trying to use itemize inside an equation, but I am getting a bunch of errors

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{itemize}
\item V_{p}=\Biggl\{F\in\Phi\hspace{2mm}\Bigg|\begin{cases}
p^2\nmid \text{disc}(F)\hspace{1mm} \text{if}\hspace{1mm} p\neq 2
\item\text{disc}(F)\equiv 1\pmod 4 \vee \text{disc}(F)\equiv 8\vee 12 
\pmod{16} \hspace{1mm}\text{if} \hspace{1mm}p=2\Biggr\}
\end{itemize}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

so I tried with begin cases instead but I am not really satisfied with how it looks

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
V_{p}=\Biggl\{F\in\Phi\hspace{2mm}\Bigg|\begin{cases}
p^2\nmid \text{disc}(F)\hspace{1mm} \text{if}\hspace{1mm} p\neq
2\\\text{disc}(F)\equiv 1\pmod 4 \vee \text{disc}(F)\equiv 8\vee 12 
\pmod{16} \hspace{1mm}\text{if} \hspace{1mm}p=2\Biggr\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and the output
[image]

I would like to get something similar but without being forced to use ''begin cases'', I thought itemize would look better after the vertical line. Does anyone have an idea how to make this equation to look prettier?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of `cases` you could use `gathered`.  And instead of the manual `\hspace`, it would be better if you just left a space in the `\text{}` macro which is where you want the space anyway.

Comment: @user124471 you could also use `aligned` within the `equation` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with small bullets, and your code simplified, using the `nccmath` , `relsize` and `braket` packages. I patched the definition of the `\Set` command thanks to David Carlisle to improve the spacing of the braces.
Note that "discr" is actually a math operator, and I declare it as such, in order to have better horizontal spacings.

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[textwidth = 15cm]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{lmodern, amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{braket, relsize, nccmath} 
    \renewcommand\Set[1]{%
    \csname Set \endcsname{\mskip-\medmuskip#1\mskip-\medmuskip}}%
    \DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}
     \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    V_{p}=\Set{%
    F\in\Phi | %
    \begin{medsize}\begin{array}{@{\mathsmaller{\bullet}\enspace}l@{}}
    p^2 \nmid \disc(F) \quad \text{if}\enspace p \neq 2\\[1ex]
    \disc(F)\equiv 1\pmod 4 \vee \disc(F)\equiv 8\vee 12
    \pmod{16} \quad\text{if} \enspace p =2
    \end{array}\end{medsize}
    }%
    \end{equation}

     \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid lengthy set descriptions; just provide two definitions for p different from 2 and for 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}

\begin{document}

We say that $\disc(F)$ is \emph{quozzy} if $\disc{F}\equiv1\pmod{4}$ or
$\disc(F)\equiv8\pmod{16}$ or $\disc(F)\equiv12\pmod{16}$; we shall use
this notion mostly for $p=2$; then we set
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
V_{p}&=\{\, F\in\Phi : p^2\nmid \disc(F)\,\}\quad(p\neq 2) \\
V_{2}&=\{\, F\in\Phi : \text{$\disc(F)$ is quozzy}\,\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Choose a better word than “quozzy”.

[image]